# How to Read/Save Text from a URL in using URLConnection

Tags: android, url

I am totally new to Android but want to make a simple Android application that displays the state of my LEDs that I have on my breadboard. So far, I've used an ESP8266 to create a server that says "LED ON" (using [this](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp8266-thing-development-board-hookup-guide/example-sketch-web-server) guide) and now I want to just display that string on my app in a textview or something.

Every helpful online resource I've seen uses the outdated apache HTTPClient method in Android Studio, but I need to use URLConnect on API 23. Below is what I have so far. When I try stepping through the code, the exception handler gets called when it executes the line starting with "BufferedReader", so I know there's something going on around there.

NOTE: I've added the following to my Android Manifest as well:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Anyone know what's going on, or can fix my code? Thanks for any help! As a beginner to Android programming, I really appreciate it! Below is the code in my .java file.

```
public void run ()
{
        esp_message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.esp_msg_txb);
        btn_connect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn_connect.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                URL url = new URL("http://thing.local/led/1");
                                URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
                                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                        new InputStreamReader(
                                                yc.getInputStream()));
                                String inputLine;
                                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                                    builder.append(inputLine.trim());
                                in.close();
                                String message = builder.toString();
                                esp_message.setText(message);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex) {
                                Log.e("Fail 1", ex.toString());
                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid IP Address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.i("Error on load data:", "" + ex.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            }
    );




}
```

Comment: what you get on click of button..?? Getting some error or exception.? if so then provide your `Logcat`.

Comment: `ex.getMessage()`. What does it print?

Comment: Please remove Android Studio from the subject of your post as this has nothing to do with it.

Comment: `thing.local`. Please explain. Why not an ip?

Comment: How are you using the esp? As accesspoint? Or client?

Comment: You were totally right, @greenapps, I was being stupid and not using my ESP as an AP; and you were also right, the "http://thing.local/led/1" should've been "http://192.168.4.1". After making those changes, I am able to do what I wanted. Thanks for the replies!